# How do I mock a class method callback called via an onClick event in React/Enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have the following simple React component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Button extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }

  handleClick () {
    console.log('clicked')
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Test</button>
    )
  }
}

export default Button
```

And the following test:

```
import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import Button from './button'
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'

import Enzyme from 'enzyme'
Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })

it('handles a click event', () => {
  const button = shallow(<Button />)
  button.instance().handleClick = jest.fn()
  button.find('button').simulate('click')
  expect(button.instance().handleClick).toHaveBeenCalledWith()
})
```

The test is failing because the `handleClick` mock has not been called. I'm guessing this is because my mock is being placed after `this.handleClick` has been rendered, and so it's not mocking the `handleClick` class method on the instance. However, I can't seem to figure out how to make this work.

What I'm trying to understand is *why* this code doesn't work, and how to make the unit test work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mock the function before shallow/mount.

So that shallow/mount component uses your mocked function and not the original function.

```
describe("Foo", () => {

    it("should bubble the event up and call parent's handleClick", () => {
        const handleClick = jest.spyOn(Foo.prototype, 'handleClick') //spy on handleClick function
        const wrapper = mount(<Foo />);
        wrapper.find('button').simulate('click'); //finding the button and simulating click
        expect(handleClick).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1) //verify function was called after click simulation
    })

})
```

Check out a working example here https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-babbage-tl8ub

Note : Go into the tests tab to run all tests.

Hope that clarifies it!

Comment: it works, thank you! My question is, _why_ is this necessary? It seems that `wrapper.instance().handleClick` is different from the callback called by `wrapper.find('button').simulate('click')`. Is it because the `instance` returned by `wrapper.instance()` is a new instance, different from the one operated on by `wrapper.find('button')`?

Comment: Exactly! you should mock a function before you instantiate the component.

Comment: The one you mock and the one the instance uses are two different functions altogether. Hence it is necessary to it that way.